# Proving Cauchy-Schwarz for general vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am asked to prove Cauchy-Schwarz $|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|\le|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|$ for general vectors in $R^n$. Is my solution correct?

$$f(\lambda)=|\vec{u}+\lambda\vec{v}|^2 \ge 0, \lambda\in R$$
$$|\vec{u}+\lambda\vec{v}|^2=(\vec{u}+\lambda\vec{v})\cdot(\vec{u}+\lambda\vec{v})=|\vec{u}|^2+\lambda^2|\vec{v}|^2+2\lambda(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})$$
Derivative:
$$f'(\lambda)=2\lambda|\vec{v}|^2+2(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})$$$$f'=0\Leftrightarrow \lambda=\frac{-(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})}{|\vec{v}|^2}$$
Insert $\lambda=\frac{-(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})}{|\vec{v}|^2}$ into $f(\lambda)$:
$$|\vec{u}|^2+\frac{(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})^2}{|\vec{v}|^4}|\vec{v}|^2-2\frac{(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})^2}{|\vec{v}|^2}\ge0$$$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}|^2|\vec{v}|^2\ge(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})^2$$$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}|^2|\vec{v}|^2\ge |\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|^2$$$$\Leftrightarrow |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\ge |\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|$$

Comment: vectors u and v are constant and $\lambda$ is the variable. Do I need to prove the diffenrentiablility beyond that?

Comment: Your solution is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is correct, but you should treat the case $\vec{v}=0$ separately.

It can be simplified: if $\vec{v}=0$, there is nothing to prove. If $\vec{v}\ne0$, the polynomial
$$
f(\lambda)=\lambda^2|\vec{v}|^2+2\lambda(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})+|\vec{u}|^2
$$
assumes only nonnegative values if and only if its discriminant is $\le0$, so we get
$$
4(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v})^2-4|\vec{u}|^2|\vec{v}|^2\le0
$$
which is the same as
$$
|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|\le|\vec{u}|\,|\vec{v}|
$$

Comment: Thank you. I am always concerned that I reach the correct answer in an incorrect way, so the correction is greatly appreciated.